# What is the difference between data-sly-use, data-sly-resource, data-sly-include, and data-sly-template?

Tags: aem, sightly

What is the difference between: `data-sly-use`, `data-sly-resource`, `data-sly-include`, and `data-sly-template`? I am reading the doc on `Sightly` `AEM` and I am super confused.

As far as I can see:

- `data-sly-use` is used to add `js/java` files to render with the doc
- `data-sly-resource` is used to inject components
- `data-sly-include` is used to include other html files (?***?)

And, data-sly-template is confusing, as in:

```
<div data-sly-use.nav="navigation.js">${nav.foo}</div>
<section data-sly-include="path/to/template.html"></section>
<template data-sly-template.one>blah</template>
<div data-sly-call="${one}"></div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you already said:

- *data-sly-use* "is used to add js/java". You declare component-beans with this statement for instance.
- *data-sly-resource* you can override a resource-type for a included file.
- *data-sly-include* includes other html files as the name suggests.
- *data-sly-template* you declare templates which can later be
  'called' with *data-sly-call*.

Please refere to the official specs for more informations. there are several examples for each tag:

https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md

Comment: I still feel this is a very brief explanation. Need more clarification with examples for this.

Comment: `data-sly-use` can be used with a resource path too, e.g. you can do `<sly data-sly-use.parsys=${resource.path}/parsys>` for example in order to loop over children with `data-sly-list=${parsys.listChildren}`

Answer (score 4):

- data-sly-use - is same what @chrysler quoted.
- **data-sly-include vs data-sly-resource** -  data-sly-resource creates a new internal request against the sling engine, where as data-sly-include looks for the specified script/servlet and executes it, using the same request context, i.e. the same current resource.

From Docs - https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/block-statements.html - 
**data-sly-include**: Replaces the content of the host element with the markup generated by the indicated HTML template file (HTL, JSP, ESP etc.) when it is processed by its corresponding template engine. The rendering context of the included file will not include the current HTL context (that of the including file);

The answer is relevant for v6.3.