# Accessing page properties of another template AEM 6.4

Tags: aem, sightly

I am trying to add a class 'feed-test' to 'template-one' based on the boolean value of a checkbox property on 'template-two.' I have read through [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382925/what-is-the-difference-between-data-sly-use-data-sly-resource-data-sly-include) regarding block statements, but still struggling.

Here's the file structure and code:

**Directory structure**

```
structure/
├── template-one/ 
│   ├── body.html
│   └── .content.xml   
└── template-two/
      ├── _cq_dialog 
      │   └──  .content.xml
      └── other files
```

**template-one where i need to add class**

```
<div class="base-wrapper INSERT-FEED-TEST-CLASS-HERE">
<sly data-sly-use.templatedContainer="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.TemplatedContainer"
     data-sly-repeat.child="${templatedContainer.structureResources}"
     data-sly-resource="${child.path @ resourceType=child.resourceType, decorationTagName='div'}"/>
```

**template-two class property i need to access**

```
<isFeedPage
    cq:showOnCreate="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/checkbox"
    cq-msm-lockable="isFeedPage"
    fieldLabel="Is Feed Page"
    text="Is Feed Page"
    name="./isFeedPage"
    granite:class="feed-test">
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but the question itself feels wrong, because page != template and also template != component. If you are actually talking about content (pages and instances of components) then you have SlingModels, the current request and with that you can get all the data you might need.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place for [HTL's Use API](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#4-use-api): you need to deploy some code that will be able to retrieve the needed template (using [TemplateManager#getTemplate](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/TemplateManager.html#getTemplate-java.lang.String-) for example) and fetch the needed property.

Then you'd use it like:

```
<div data-sly-use.classProvider="MyClassProvider" class="base-wrapper ${classProvider.className}">
...
</div>
```